# set environment variables for system() in R?

Tags: r, ubuntu, system, environment-variables, bash

I've been using R in Ubuntu to make system calls using `system()` for things like spinning up Amazon EC2 instances, managing files on S3, etc. If I start R from the command line everything works fine. But if I start R from a script using Rscript, or from ESS, I have issues with environment variables not being set.

I **think** this is an issue with me not properly grokking where to set environment variables in Ubuntu. I thought the "right place" (for some definition of "right") was to set user environment variables in ~/.bashrc. This is where I set things like `export EC2_HOME=/home/jd/ec2` but when I execute R from ESS and make system calls, the .bashrc script is not being run. I've tried Googing about and I see many an exegesis on environment variables in Ubuntu, such as [this one](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?s=828aae97393039af756ddcd9ca72a894&t=2793). My knee jerk reaction is to try each recommendation in the aforementioned thread and stop giving a shit as soon as one of the options works. But then I end up with non-standard settings which bite me in the ass later.

So how should I set environment variables so that they are properly set when I run a `system()` call in R?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you are confusing the issue.  I fear this may be about login shells versus non-login shells.  See the bash manual page for the fine print ... which has driven me bonkers in the past.

That said, if you can set environment variables system-wide, you have a few options:

- `/etc/environment` is a very good place as it is shell-agnostic should you ever use a different shell
- for login versus non-login shells, the one way to get complete control that I found suitable was to put *my* changes into something like `~/.local_bashrc`
- the add `. ~/.local_bashrc` from and and all of

  - `~./bashrc`
  - `~/.bash_profile`
  - ~/.profile`

  etc pp.

You can precede the sourcing with a `echo Hello from FILE` where you replace FILE with the name of the file.  That shows you the difference between shells starting from login (eg via `gdm` et al), via `ssh` connection, via new `xterm` etc terminals and so on.

Comment: Damn good tips, as always Dirk. I was tempted to start editing `/etc/environment` but every time I start to screw around with something in `/etc/` I hear a German accented voice say very softly 've are not learning very fast, are ve?' and I kinda get creeped out and reconsider my decision to leave the family farm and pursue life in the big city.

Answer (score 10):

You can try to set them in R itself using `Sys.setenv`.

Comment: well shit. I was trying to do this through the Ubuntu approach and didn't realize there was an R approach. Thank you!

Comment: And `Renviron`. `Renviron.site` and `~/.Renviron`.

Answer (score 0):

You can force the system to read your .bashrc file by using the source command

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

Lots of inelegant and ugly ways to apply this