# Setting R environmental variable in Tortoise SVN

Tags: r, svn, environment-variables

I have a collection of functions in a file called *some_functions.R* and saved in a SVN directory in *C:\blah1\blah2\Rcodes\some_functions.R* . I have several Rprojects which uses this code file. Say a R project is available in the directory *C:\blah1\blah2\Rprojects\project1*. I can use hard coded path to  refer the file and it works.

```
source("C:/blah1/blah2/Rcodes/some_functions.R")'
```

**But I would like to set the path as environmental variable.**

Looking at [How to unfold user and environment variable in R language?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18669886/how-to-unfold-user-and-environment-variable-in-r-language) and [setting the home directory in windows R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13016907/setting-the-home-directory-in-windows-r)  I add the following line in the RProfile.site file

```
Sys.setenv(R_CODE_PATH = "C:/blah1/blah2/Rcodes")
```

and in the project1.Rnw file

```
source("R_CODE_PATH/some_functions.R")
```

But the project file can not read the some_functions.R file. I tried with %R_CODE_PATH% without any luck.

Not sure what I'm missing here. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Consider using projects, either in RStudio or RTVS (R Tools for Visual Studio). This will set the R working directory to the project directory, so you don't have to mess with the environment yourself.

Comment: @Hong Ooi 3, I'm using RStudio projects but the problem was to linking an external collection of code file in the project file. Since the code file is used in several projects, I don't want to copy it inside every project directory but rather keep it at one place and update/change in one file only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You retrieve environment variables using `Sys.getenv()`. Try:

```
r_code_path <- Sys.getenv("R_CODE_PATH")
```

Then, for example:

```
source(paste(r_code_path, "some_functions.R", sep = "/"))
```

I would use the `.Renviron` config file to define environment variables. Put it in whatever directory the R command `Sys.getenv("HOME")` returns and include lines like this:

```
R_CODE_PATH=C:/blah1/blah2/Rcodes
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked!  I use     _source(paste(Sys.getenv("R_CODE_PATH"),"some_funcitons.R", sep="/"))_ in one go.

Comment: I tried .Renviron way earlier too without any success. In this second approach does it overwrite the environment path already created?  Ahhh.. I was putting the .Renviron file in the wrong directory, my bad.

Comment: I am not sure about precedence and overwriting; I'd just choose one system and stick with it if it works.